# Primefaces push with dynamic paths is not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, wildfly, atmosphere, primefaces-push

I tried to implement the [chat sample](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.jsf) of primefaces-push, but it doesn't working.

I run some tests and i figured out that using @PushEndpoint with fixed paths e.g. */channel*, it works properly, however, using path params e.g. */channel/{userId}*, the socket doesn't receive any message.

I'm using:

- Wildfly 9.0.0-Final
- Primefaces 5.2
- Atmosphere 2.3.3

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It works with Atmosphere 2.3.4.

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow isn't like an old fashioned discussion forum wherein everyone edits the title to include some tag to indicate the state of the question. Just post it as an answer and mark it accepted. Additional advantage is that it shows differently in the listing and is explicitly indexable and searchable as such.

Comment: And please revert the question to.

Answer (score 0):

It works when switching to atmosphere 2.3.4