# Primefaces Push can't get dynamic path to work

Tags: primefaces, push, atmosphere

This works:

Facelet snippet:

```
<p:socket channel="/redirectMonitoring">
    <p:ajax event="message" oncomplete="window.location.replace('/foo.xhtml')" />
</p:socket>
```

Resource:

```
@PushEndpoint("/redirectMonitoring")
@Singleton
public class RedirectMonitorResource {
    @OnMessage() public void onMessage(Boolean ignore) {}
}
```

CDI bean:

```
@Model
public class RedirectBean {
    public void redirect() {
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish("/redirectMonitoring", Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

But when I try to make the path dynamic as follows:

Facelet:

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/redirectMonitoring/{sessionId}" autoConnect="false" widgetVar='subscriber'/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleMessage(message) {
        window.location.replace(message);
    }
</script>
```

Bean that connects via session ID:

```
@Model
public class LoginController {
    private void onLogin(@Observes @LoggedIn User loggedInUser) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(
            "PF('subscriber').connect('/redirectMonitoring/" + WebUtil.getSession().getId() + "')");
    }
}
```

Resource:

```
@PushEndpoint("/redirectMonitoring/{sessionId}")
@Singleton
public class RedirectMonitorResource {
    @PathParam("sessionId") private String sessionId;

    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class}) public String onMessage(String message) { return message; }
}
```

CDI bean:

```
@Model
public class RedirectBean {
    public void redirect(String sessionId) {
        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish("/redirectMonitoring/" + sessionId, "/foo.xhtml");
    }
}
```

The web browser does not load /foo.xhtml and I get the following error in the log:

```
20:12:24,811 ERROR [org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint] (default I/O-5) : java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:375) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.read(NioSocketConduit.java:280) [xnio-nio-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at org.xnio.conduits.AbstractStreamSourceConduit.read(AbstractStreamSourceConduit.java:51) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at org.xnio.ssl.JsseSslStreamSourceConduit.read(JsseSslStreamSourceConduit.java:84) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at io.undertow.conduits.IdleTimeoutConduit.read(IdleTimeoutConduit.java:144)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSourceChannel.read(ConduitStreamSourceChannel.java:127) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedChannel.receive(AbstractFramedChannel.java:244)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.AbstractReceiveListener.handleEvent(AbstractReceiveListener.java:20)
    at io.undertow.websockets.core.AbstractReceiveListener.handleEvent(AbstractReceiveListener.java:15)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedChannel$FrameReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractFramedChannel.java:632)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.framed.AbstractFramedChannel$FrameReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractFramedChannel.java:618)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:87) [xnio-nio-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539) [xnio-nio-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
```

P.S.  I did set breakpoints to ensure that the session id in

```
"PF('subscriber').connect('/redirectMonitoring/" + WebUtil.getSession().getId() + "')"
```

matched the session id in

```
eventBus.publish("/redirectMonitoring/" + sessionId, "/foo.xhtml");
```

Any suggestions/pointers/advice would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2 + Atmosphere 2.3.4.

I did change `p:socket` to `autoConnect="true"` but doing so did not help.

Here's what I see via the browser console/network tab when the browser makes a request against the web application:

```
https://localhost:8443/app/primepush/redirectMonitoring/%7BsessionId%7D?X-Atmosphere-Transport=close&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=5f40ca65-0ab0-4c4c-ab58-7b9b790eb78f&_=1440535767013
```

[image: Browser console/network tab]

However, when the web application attempts to send a message to the web browser via the `/redirectMonitoring` endpoint I see no activity on the console/network tab.

Here's another clue:

When I set a breakpoint at RedirectMonitorResource#onMessage in the static path version, the breakpoint is triggered in debugging session:

```
@PushEndpoint("/redirectMonitoring")
@Singleton
public class RedirectMonitorResource {
    @OnMessage() 
    public void onMessage(Boolean ignore) {} // <-- breakpoint here is triggered
}
```

However, when I set a breakpoint in the dynamic path version, the breakpoint is *not* triggered.  RedirectMonitorResource#onMessage does not get invoked in the dynamic path version:

```
@PushEndpoint("/redirectMonitoring/{sessionId}")
@Singleton
public class RedirectMonitorResource {
    @PathParam("sessionId") private String sessionId;

    @OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class}) 
    public String onMessage(String message) { 
        return message;                          // <-- breakpoint here not triggered 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749009/primefaces-push-with-dynamic-paths-is-not-working

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate because (1) that question does not indicate that an exception is being thrown and (2) I'm using Primefaces 2.3.4, which was the answer offered in that question.  Is there not any simple working example using dynamic paths available online other than the chat application?  All the examples use static paths.

Comment: Atmosphere 2.3.4 you mean. Please add all this kind of info to the question. And absence of the mentioning of an error in log does not mean there was none. Does it work with autoconnect=true? And what about the browser console/network tab? Any info?

Comment: And the other post contains an example. And what is wrong with the showcase example?

Comment: Ah yes Atmosphere 2.3.4 (atmosphere-2.3.4 tag was not available when I posted the question).  Good point about absence of mentioning error in log. I updated the question to answer your questions.

Comment: Yes, other post contains the chat sample, which is more complex than what I am doing (e.g. seven classes, multiple PathParams, OnOpen, OnClose, etc. etc.).  I don't want to pollute application code I'm working on with the chat example or create a new demo application just to debug. Doing so would require a lot more work than making a few simple changes to an already existing code (static path) that is already working properly in my web application.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change p:socket channel attribute from this:

```
<p:socket channel="/redirectMonitoring/{sessionId}" ... />
```

to this:

```
<p:socket channel="/redirectMonitoring/#{session.id}" ... />
```

Comment: Great it works and sorry I missed that. But as stated above, the showcase works, so 'comparing' it to your example is always good.

Comment: @Kukeltje I did try to get the show case to work after reading your advice.  I removed the JSF JAR so that it would deploy properly to Wildfly.  Then, I enabled chat.xhtml's `Username: inputText` and the `commandButton`, which were disabled.  But it didn't work properly.  I was able to get the users to show up in each other's `Users dataList` but alas no messages back and forth.  But anyway, it's a different issue, and I did try.